# VBA copy rows to empty rows in other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to copy data from worksheet A to worksheet B.
Worksheet A is just filled with data without any layout.
Worksheet B has a particular layout in which the data of worksheet A should be pasted.
Worksheet B has a header in the first 10 rows, so the copying should start at row 11. Data in worksheet A start at row 2. So row2(A)=>row11(B), row3(A)=>row12(B),...
The code for this part of the problem included below.

The condition I'm struggling with is that only rows without a value in colum F in worksheet B should be used. 
So par example if  rows 11-61 in worksheet B have no value in column F, rows 2-52 of worksheet A should be pasted in rows 11-61 in worksheet B. If cell F62 isn't empty, that row should be skipped en the next row of worksheet A (row 52) should be pasted in row 63 in worksheet B. And so on, till the next row with data in column F.

The code so far:

```
Sub RO()
'
' RO Macro
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+Shift+S
'

    Dim a As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SO")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RO")

    j = 11     ' Start copying to row 11 in target sheet
    For Each a In Source.Range("A2:A10000")   ' Do 10000 rows
        If a <> "" Then
           Source.Rows(a.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           Target.Rows(j).Value = Source.Rows(a.Row).Value
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next a
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use this piece of code to copy paste values.
its pretty quick

```
    Public Sub Copy()

        Dim Source As Worksheet
        Dim SourceRow As Long
        Dim SourceRange As String

        Dim Target As Worksheet
        Dim TargetRow As Long
        Dim TargetRange As String

        Dim ColumnCount As Long

        Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1")
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad2")

        TargetRow = 11
        ColumnCount = Source.UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For SourceRow = 1 To Source.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            SourceRange = Range(Cells(SourceRow, 1), Cells(SourceRow, ColumnCount)).Address

While Target.Cells(TargetRow, 6).value <> ""
TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
Wend

TargetRange = Range(Cells(TargetRow, 1), Cells(TargetRow, ColumnCount)).Address

Target.Range(TargetRange).Value = Source.Range(SourceRange).Value

            TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: This does indeed work. Think the solution to implementing the condition (F column is empty) probably could work with an if statement with the If Cells(TargetRow, F) is empty, paste, otherwise move to the next row. 
But not really an idea how to translate this into working VBA code :)

Comment: So it needs to search for a row where Column F is not filled?

Comment: The While command creates an error when I try to execute the macro

Comment: Is it a captial C for cells? I'm on my phone right now so doing it from my head, but you basically keep looping until you find an empty cells

Comment: Oh wait try: 'Wend' instead of 'End While'

Comment: Perfect! Can you edit that in the code above? I'll mark it as answer.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 2 separate counts, 1 to keep track of the source rows you are trying to copy, and another to keep track of the target rows you are trying to paste.  then you can increment them independently depending if a row passes a criteria etc.

If you are pasting blocks have 2 sets of row counts: source start & source end, paste start & paste end.  Not fancy, but allows max control and processing of exceptions etc.

Comment: So first defining all the target ranges p.e. 2-35, 36-78, 81-92,... and afterwards with this info defining the source ranges?